# xrdp mount cd manually

Tags: nautilus, permissions, automount, xrdp

I am running ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 64 bit

I work through remote connection using xrdp. The problem is when I connect remotely I cannot access CD/DVD drive but I can see the icon in nautilus. When I click it I have Error saying mount failed

I need every time to mount it manually using command line

```
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cd
```

and when I mount it from remote connection, the console session cannot access the cd. the error is saying permission denied. maybe because of the sudo command I used in remote connection

How can I read my cd from both console and remote sessions without manually mounting it.

Answer (score 1):

Create inside the /media directory the directory where you want to mount your dvd. In example

```
mkdir /media/sasha
```

Then figure out where your dvd can be found using the command `lshw` and look for something like `/dev/srX` where X is a digit.

In my case the dvd was on `sr0` so I needed to execute:

```
mount -t iso9660 -o loop /dev/sr0 /media/sasha
```

Comment: please read the question carefully. How can I read my cd from both console and remote sessions without manually mounting it.